# Laravel checking for Boolean always returns true

Tags: php, laravel, boolean

Here is the query result for

> $customer = Customer::where('contact',$contact)->first();

```
  App\Customer {#2382                             
       id: 11,                                       
       name: "sai",                                  
       gender: null,                                 
       dob: null,                                    
       email: "#######@gmail.com",             
       contact: "########",                         
       newsletter: 0,                                
       authy_id: "",                                 
       verified: 1,                                  
       blocked: 0,                                   
       cuid: "7D968C49-4029-77BE-692C-67AF002099F6", 
       created_at: "2018-05-20 13:19:34",            
       updated_at: "2018-05-20 13:41:12",            
       deleted_at: null,                             
       rewardPoints: 0,                              
     }
```

and when I look for the column 'blocked'

> $customer->blocked

I get its value `0`

But when I sue a conditional statement

```
if( $customer->blocked == true ) 
 {                                
 echo 'true' ;                  
 }
```

or

```
  if( $customer->blocked == 1) 
     {                                
     echo 'true' ;                  
     }
```

It always returns a positive result. Even tho the value is `0`
Edit: here's a screenshot php artisan tinker

[image]

Comment: have you tried `if($customer->blocked === 1)`? It could be a type issue.

Comment: Yep still getting the same error.

Comment: Where are you doing this check? There must be a conflict somewhere. Have you tried `dd($customer->blocked)` in the exact line where you do the check?

Comment: dd($customer->blocked) returns 0

Comment: Even if you put it inside the if statement, i.e. `if (...) { dd(...); }`????

Comment: Yes  if( $customer->blocked === 1) dd($customer->blocked); returns 0

Comment: Your last comment saying that it it returns 0 when $customr->blocked ===1 which is a little bit weird

Comment: I'm getting the same result for both if($customer->blocked === 1) and if($customer->blocked === 0)

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: Check this `$customer->blocked == true  ? 1 : 0;`